# How can I select a sentence from a text with protractor?

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor, sendkeys

I have to text a rich text editor using protractor. I want to select a sentence from the text and then click on the bold button to make this sentence bold.

I have tried some tests to select all the text, but it is not working. I am using a MAC computer.

```
browser.actions().keyDown(protractor.Key.COMMAND).sendKeys('a').perform();
```

How can I achieved it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [protractor-hotkeys](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-hotkeys) package can help here. Let me know if you need some sample of it.

Comment: Thanks for your kick answer, so for a mac, it would be something like that: hotkeys.trigger('mod+a'); is it correct?

Comment: It is not throwing any error, but I am using debug mode and the text is not being selected.

Comment: Try to execute it without debug mode? (This action will not execute if you are operating mouse as its completely depends on what is in focus now on your system)

Comment: ok, if I execute it the test passes but I can't see if it is selecting the text because it is too quickly. Thanks for your help! Is there any way to select just a sentence from the text?

Comment: Right. You can add wait after performing all selection.