# why is hotkeys.trigger not working in a mac?

Tags: angularjs, macos, selenium, protractor, hotkeys

I am using this command in protractor to undo the text inserted in a certain element. However, it is not working because the text is not undone. Why?

The command used is:

```
hotkeys.trigger('mod+z',{targetElement: $(properties.homePage.editableText)});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try [protractor-hotkeys](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-hotkeys) package here, As it will help to execute same code on different os. Let me know if you need any sample for this.

also you can refer [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53319216/how-can-i-select-a-sentence-from-a-text-with-protractor/53319392#53319392)

Comment: Thanks, indeed I am using protractor-hotkeys but it is not working.